# Rails 4 accordion issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am trying to use accordion menu in my project but I am failing miserably

```
<li class="accordion">
                            <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i><span> menu name</span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                <li><a href="#"> 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"> 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"> 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"> 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"> 5</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

what I did was the following based on the answers in Stackoverflow but none seems to work

1.Installed jquery turbolinks it didnt work

2. Removed turbolinks it didnt work
3. added new jqueryui downloaded from the jquery ui site but still didnt work

Anything Else I should try to work with Accordion menu in rails 4?
my application .js

```
 //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require jquery-ui.js
    //= require bootstrap.js
```

logs

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-04 12:51:07 +0530


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-04 12:51:07 +0530


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-04 12:51:07 +0530


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-04 12:51:07 +0530
```

Comment: We would need much more info. then this to help you out . Have you included the downloaded jquery in application.js file ?

Comment: added the application.js code

Comment: What's the actual name of the file you downloaded , is it jqueryui or jquery-ui ?

Comment: jquery-ui.js is the one

Comment: ok , now do a rake assets:precompile

Comment: Also , do remove all the .js . For example - jquery-ui.js -> jquery-ui

Comment: done rake assets:precompile and renamed still the same issue

Comment: Can you post the logs when u open the page , i just want to see if the jquery-ui gets called then .

Comment: now $("#accordion").accordion(); results as object[] but the menu is not expanding

Comment: Take the example code from the accordion example site and try paste it there to see if it works

Comment: Also , do clear the browser cache .

Comment: thanks for the help removed few scripts and then it worked .. was a multiple jquery reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="accordion1">
            **<li class="panel">** 
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#firstLink">Test12</a>
              <ul id="firstLink" class="collapse panel-collapse in">
                    <li>SubTest1</li>
                    <li>SubTest1</li>
                    <li>SubTest1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

adding  worked